# Control Amplifier from Computer via RS232

Tags: macos, usb, serial, rs232, hexadecimal

I got a second hand Rotel RSX-1056 amplifier that I would like to control from my computer (because I don't have the remote).

The amplifier has a serial port (RS232) and on the web I was able to find a specification for the communications:
http://www.rotel.com/sites/default/files/product/rs232/RSX1056%20Protocol.pdf

My computer is a hackintosh running OS X 10.11.3.

So I bought an FTDI serial (RJ45) to USB cable and tried to send some messages to the amp. I wasn't sure how to change the buad speed etc on OS X because stty on OS X seems to be problematic in this regard and sets it back to the value it was upon quitting. Regardless of that I tried running something like (the code to bring the volume up):

`echo -ne '\xFE\x03\xC5\x10\x0B\xE3' > /dev/tty.usb-serial`

and it hangs.

I replace the `tty` with `cu` and it doesn't hang, but nothing happens.

I tried using CoolTerm for Mac OS X;  I was able to get some data sent to the computer from the amp when changing the volume knob physically on the amp, but when I tried to send an hex code from computer to amp via CoolTerm, again, nothing happens.

Here are some screen shots from CoolTerm:
[image: Settings]
[image: Receiving data from amplifier after changing volume on its front panel]
[image: Trying to send data--nothing happens]

At that point I started thinking that maybe the FTDI Mac OS X drivers are faulty. So I tried to use a Windows VM with the FTDI and that also didn't help (getting data when pressing physical buttons on amp, and nothing happens when sending data to amp).

I also tried to use a VM with Ubuntu, in which case stty *does* work, but again, hexdump -C shows data sent from amp, but echo doesn't do anything or hangs.

At this point I started suspecting that the chip I have is faulty, so I purchased a PL2303 USB to serial adaptor. I installed the Prolific drivers, and again, the whole same thing happens: can receive data, and when sending nothing happens.

If anyone has *any* advice about this I would be most grateful, as right now I have no way to change the volume on the amp other than getting up and turning the knob.

Comment: Have you thought about buying a universal remote controller?

Comment: @DavidPostill, Yeah I did, but I'm a bit wary of it because I don't have the original remote, so I'm not sure how to "teach" the remote, and the ones I know for sure work with it (like the Logitech Harmony) are quite costly. In addition, I already have a HTPC keyboard+mouse from logitech and I would prefer to have only one controller instead of two.

Comment: Extra remark for any Windows user: American B&W Support has ready-made projects for the Rotel products, including Rotel RSX-1056, using Docklight: http://bwgroupsupport.com/download/rs232-resources (no license required for using these projects).